# Webservices: Why use soap engine and application server?

Tags: java, web-services

First sorry for my english. I am currently trying to develop a JAVA webservice for Android devices. More precisely, the webservice provider would be an ordinary computer and webservices clients would be Android devices.

After I have read some tutorials, I have done [this one](http://www.java-forums.org/blogs/web-service/1145-how-create-java-web-service.html) (webservice + client), which require only Eclipse. Everything works OK. So my question is the following: given that my webservice is working well and is accessible, why would I use soap engine and application server, as mentionned in this [short introduction to webservice](http://gdp.globus.org/gt4-tutorial/multiplehtml/ch01s02.html) ? Said another way, what are the advantages, concretely?

I have tried to google, read and learn more, but I am stuck at this point.. If I have well-understood, SOAP engines, like Apache AXIS, allow to dynamically generate SOAP data and to receive requests from different clients. But does not my webservice already generate automatically SOAP requests/responses, since I can use my webservice with my dedicated client?

Regarding application server, I just can't figure out what it is. I found few documentation about that I could understand.

I know that instead of asking these kind of question, a better way would be to practice myself soap engine and application server, but I would prefer to know what I am doing and using rather than to go in a "random mode".

I hope I've been clear, thanks a lot for you answers.

MCFarah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked a couple of questions which are quite heavy, but i'll try to give a brief overview:

1. Web/Application Servers are basically a piece of program that implements a lot of stuff that help the developer, by allowing him to focus on the actual development and not on the stuff around. Stuff like: Threads, security, Database connection pooling etc.
2. You don't have to use SOAP webservice, actually I think you'd be better off using [REST](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html).
3. The tutorial you did is a "Hello World" tutorial. It is only good for getting started but once you start writing a larger application you would want to use a web server. Id recommend starting with [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/).

Just start using the technologies and post questions as you go.

Comment: I will do what you're saying (REST web-service) and come back if I need.